# Add a constant force in Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a ball and I want to move it on the X axis, so, in the FixedUpdate method I added a force:

```
rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.right * speed);
```

The ball's speed increases because of this code I wrote. I want to make this force to be constant, so the ball's speed not to increase. How can I do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a constant force will accelerate the object, because that's how real physics work:

```
Force = mass * acceleration
```

In your case, the resulting acceleration is:

```
Acceleration = Force / mass
```

If you want to set the object speed to be constant, you should modify the rigidBody's velocity:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html

Something like this:

```
rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And if I want that not to affect my gravity should I write rigidbody2D.velocity.y instead of 0?